# Override a function from ui-bootsrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've included the **angular-bootstrap** library in my application using bower.

I'm currently using a (old) **version containing a bug** which is solved in a newer version. However, in my situation an **upgrade is not yet possible**.

I also thought of adding a custom modified js file below the importlines of bower in my `index.html` page, but compile errors occur.

I know exactly the right LOC containing the bug in the .js of the library `ui-bootstrap.js`, but these changes wouldn't be appropriate in that file because I develop in automated building system that would just overwrite my changes.

Therefore, **I'd like to overwrite the function** in the place (controller or service of the page) where I call of the bugged function.

Is this even possible? If so, how can I best overwrite it?

Comment: hacking your automation build is better than hacking your code in this way

Comment: @Ahmad Couldn't agree more with you. And it will happen in a few weeks, it's just that the upgrade requires a new version of bootstrap, which requires a new version of angular, which forces me to change pretty much the whole website. Even though this job is planned for in a few weeks, currently I need to come up with a 'quick' solution.

Comment: What kind of compile error do you get? why did you get that? how do you compile your code?

Comment: typically overwrite it is not the best way. The quickest way is to copy the bugged directive into a renamed custom version of the directive, fix the bug and make it available for normal use. The only issue is that you are tying your code to a particular version of the library, that means poor flexibility for future changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a decorator for the method you want change.

Suppose your factory looks like below

```
app.factory('myService',function(){
  return {
    getData: function() {
      // your code
    }
  };
});
```

Now if you want to change the functionality of getData() function, you can do it like below

```
app.config(function($provide) {

  $provide.decorator('myService', function($delegate) {
    var oldFunc = $delegate.getData;
    $delegate.getData = function() {
      // your updated code
      return oldFunc();
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

Comment: The idea is good, but a code snippet would be much better than a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Fork `angular-bootstrap` on github, make the desired changes, and use a git url in `bower.json`, like:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-bootstrap": "git@github.com:yourgithubuser/angular-bootstrap.git"
  }
}
```